# Footer appears behind content instead of the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, alignment

Well title speaks for itself,

I have a footer that I expect to at the bottom of the page, but instead it appears behind content.

You can see the problem here: http://inelmo.com (I made footer black so you can see it)

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
   <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="content"> !There is php stuff echoed here! </div>
      <div id="sidebar"></div>
      <div id="footer"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 902px;
    margin: 70px auto 0 auto;
}

#content {
    width: 520px;
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
}

#footer {
    background: #000;
    height: 200px;
}

/* Sidebar */
#sidebar {
    width: 336px;
    float: right;
    padding: 16px 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `clear: both;` to your footer's style definition

```
#footer {
    background: #000;
    height: 200px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Worked ;) Thank you I can accept the answer in 5 min, while waiting can you explain what "clear" is used for?

Answer (score 2):

The clear property disables floats.

[Reference - CSS clear](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)